# How could this this equation system be transformed to a X-Y-Z linear equation system?

Tags: linear-algebra, systems-of-equations

I'm trying to solve [this problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9vMFE.png), which basically states this:

> Based on the system of equations of the variables $x, y$ and $z$:
>   $$\begin{cases}
> x y - 2\sqrt{y} + 3 y z = 8 \\
> 2 x y - 3\sqrt{y} + 2 y z = 7 \\
> - x y + \sqrt{y} + 2 y z = 4 \\
> \end{cases}$$please tell which of the next alternatives are correct:
>
> - The system is possible and determined
> - The range of the extended matrix of the system is 2.
> - On the transposed matrix of the coefficients, associated with the system: $a_{12} = -3$
> - The coefficient matrix associated to the system is non invertible.

So, what I did was construct the extended matrix from the equation system given in the problem statement, replacing the variables as this:

- $a = xy$
- $b = \sqrt{y}$
- $c = yz$

The matrix constructed is this:
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & -2 & 3 & 8 \\
2 & -3 & 2 & 7 \\
-1 & 1 & 2 & 4 
\end{bmatrix}
Solving by gaussian method, the matrix is reduced to:
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & -2 & 3 & 8 \\
0 & 1 & -4 & -9 \\
0 & 0 & 1 & 3
\end{bmatrix}

So finally:

- $a = 5$
- $b = 3$
- $c = 3$

The values of $x, y$ and $z$ could be calculated using the previous equations, giving this values as results:

- $x = 5/9$
- $y = 9$
- $z = 1/3$

This is the far as I can go on solving this problem, my question basically is, **how to transform this to a linear equation system of x, y and z**, because I do have the values of $x, y$ and $z$ but the statements that I have to indicate if they are correct or not, are based on that matrix that I don't know how to build.

I was thinking that maybe this problem doesn't look for me to build such a matrix, instead, given that there exist a solution for the system proposed initially, I should deduct the veracity of the statements:

- First statement is **correct** as each variable has just one unique value.
- Second statement is **incorrect** because for each variable having one single value, the range of the matrix should be 3.

Second and third statement I have no idea how to answer to.

Please give me a hand on this.
Thank you a lot.

Comment: It is important to include the entire question as text, instead of as images. I added the necessary [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) for you.

Comment: Thank you for including it!

Comment: I suspect that the matrix-related items refer to the coefficients of the linear "$a$-$b$-$c$" system you created by assigning $a=xy$, $b=\sqrt{y}$, $c=yz$.

Comment: It is not, the problem said "Based on the equation system of the variables **"x-y-z"**

Comment: @CarlosCórdovaS.: Well, the $x$-$y$-$z$ system is hopelessly non-linear, so there's no appropriate interpretation of "matrix of coefficients" for it. (The work you did in assigning $a$, $b$, $c$ seems exactly the correct approach.)